# Detect that MMS has been deleted

Tags: android, mms, contentobserver

Is there a way to detect that an MMS message has been deleted from the native messaging client? Right now I have an observer registered for `Mms.CONTENT_URI` but `onChange` is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register `BroadcastReceiver` for `Mms.Intents.CONTENT_CHANGED_ACTION` and get `Uri` of the deleted message from the received intent:

```
Uri u = (Uri)intent.getExtras().get(Mms.Intents.DELETED_CONTENTS);
```